# What relation does the objects have?

Tags: java

how can I explain what the relation between object C and D is?

```
public class C
{
  private D d;

  public C()
  {
     d = new D();
     d.do();
  }

  public now()
  {
    d.next();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean like class member or data member?

Comment: D is not an object. D is a class. d refers to an object of type D. d is a member variable/member field of class C... I think.

Comment: C instantiates an object of D.. that's it.

Comment: composition aka "has a" relationship. But the usage does not seem right. Also the  now () is not valid , it looks like constructor but is not. i bet it does not compile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`d` is a class member (or data member) of object type `D` that belongs to `C`. You might think of it as a "has-a" relationship (`C` has-a `D`).